# Export template class from DLL

Tags: c++, templates, dll

I've got a problem exporting a templated class from a DLL and then importing it in my application.

My project is structured like this

- CommonDLL where the base templated class (CASingleton) is defined
- CoreDLL where a class (CAEngine) is derived from CASingleton on the first DLL
- A test executable using those two DLLs

My problem now is that everything work, until I use some functions defined in the first base class (CASingleton) which is a templated class.

These are the classes:

CASingleton in the first DLL (CommonDLL)

CASingleton.h

```
template<class T>
class ANIMACOMMON_API CASingleton
{
public:
    T& CreateInstance()
    {
        assert(!m_pSingletonInstance && "Trying to create for the second time a singleton.");

        m_pSingletonInstance = new T();

        return GetInstance();
    }

    void DeleteInstance()
    {
        assert(m_pSingletonInstance);
        m_pSingletonInstance = 0;
    }

    T& GetInstance()
    {
        assert(m_pSingletonInstance);
        return *m_pSingletonInstance;
    }

    T* GetInstancePtr()
    {
        assert(m_pSingletonInstance);
        return m_pSingletonInstance;
    }

private:
    static T* m_pSingletonInstance;
};
```

CASingleton.cpp

```
#include "ASingleton.h"

template<class T> T* CASingleton<T>::m_pSingletonInstance = NULL;
```

ANIMACOMMON_API is defined like this

```
#ifdef ANIMACOMMON_EXPORTS
#define ANIMACOMMON_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ANIMACOMMON_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Then in the second DLL (CoreDLL) I have this class derived from CASingleton

CAEngine.h

```
class ANIMACORE_API CAEngine : public CASingleton<CAEngine>
{
public:
    CAEngine();
    virtual ~CAEngine();

    void Test() { int i = 0; i++; }
};
```

CAEngine.cpp

```
template class CASingleton<CAnimaEngine>;

CAnimaEngine::CAnimaEngine()
{
}    

CAnimaEngine::~CAnimaEngine()
{
}
```

ANIMACORE_API defined like this

```
#ifdef ANIMACORE_EXPORTS
#define ANIMACORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ANIMACORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

The last thing is the application which simply has a main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    CAEngine engineOne;
    engineOne.Test();
    engineOne.CreateInstance();
    CAEngine engineTwo;
}
```

All the DLLs compile fine, but when I try to compile the application the compile gives me this error

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "__declspec(dllimport) public: class CAEngine & __thiscall CASingleton<class CAEngine>::CreateInstance(void)" (__imp_?CreateInstance@?$CASingleton@VCAEngine@@@@QAEAAVCAEngine@@XZ) non risolto nella funzione _main
```

It compiles only if I comment

```
engineOne.CreateInstance();
```

The only function I use from the base class.

Any idea?

Comment: Your CASingleton.cpp is useless, move the content in header.

Comment: You mean to make CAEngine directly a singleton? I've made the base class in order to make more singleton classes without having to rewrite always the same code

Comment: You have to define `CASingleton<T>::m_pSingletonInstance` for each `T`.

Comment: For example CASingleton<CAEngine>::m_pSingletonInstance inside CAEngine.ccp?

Comment: I've tryed to add `template CAEngine* CASingleton<CAEngine>::m_pSingletonInstance;` or `CAEngine* CASingleton<CAEngine>::m_pSingletonInstance;` or `CASingleton<CAEngine>::m_pSingletonInstance;` in both CAEngine.cpp and CAEngine.h but it doesn't work. Actually the compiler says
`warning C4273: 'm_pSingletonInstance': link to dll not consistent see previous declaration`
`error C2491: 'CASingleton<CAEngine>::m_pSingletonInstance': dllimport definition on static member not allowed`

Comment: As all function are inline, you may remove `dllexport` from `CASingleton`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! But I don't really understand why I could remove dllexport. I mean, if I'm using those function outside the DLL, how the application can link to them?

Comment: You are using `CASingleton.h`/`CAEngine.h` header files in your application, don't you? So you don't need any DLL, because all code is already at these files.